# Camel: failure to add routes dynamically

Tags: java, apache-camel, tomcat7, java-7

I'm using Apache-Camel 2.15.2.

I am trying to add routes to a `CamelContext` dynamically, but I came across a problem that baffles me.

As far as I can tell, I do add the routes to the correct `CamelContext`, and it seems like their `configure()` is called without throwing exceptions. However when I try to execute the main route, I get a run time Exception telling me that the route I added dynamically does not exist.

Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
public class MainRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder
{
    public static CamelContext camelContext;

    public static boolean returnLabel = true;

    public static RouteBuilder nestedRouteBuilder;

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception
    {
        System.out.println("Building main route!");
        System.out.println("Context: " + getContext());

        camelContext = getContext();

        from("direct:mainRoute")
        //3. I do not actually want to instantiate RouteContainer like this each time I call this route.
        //I would simply want to reuse a reference to an instance I created outside of configure()...
        .to(new RouteContainer().getMyRoute(2))
        ;

        returnLabel = false;

        //configure direct:myRoute.2

        includeRoutes(nestedRouteBuilder);      
    }

}

public class RouteContainer extends RouteBuilder
{
    public Route route;

    RouteContainer() {
        super(MainRouteBuilder.camelContext);
    }

    String getMyRoute(final int n) {

        if (MainRouteBuilder.returnLabel && route == null) {
            route = new Route() {

                @Override
                public void configure()
                {

                    System.out.println("Building nested route!");
                    System.out.println("Context: " + getContext());

                    from("direct:myRoute." + n)
                    .transform()
                    .simple("number: " + n)
                    .to("stream:out")
                    .process(new Processor() {
                        @Override
                        public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                            Response response = new Response();
                            response.setStatus(Status.SUCCESS);

                            exchange.getOut().setBody(response);
                        }
                    });
                }               
            };
        }

//1. works:
        MainRouteBuilder.nestedRouteBuilder = this;

//2. does not work:
//      RouteContainer routeContainer = new RouteContainer();
//      routeContainer.route = this.route;
//      MainRouteBuilder.nestedRouteBuilder = routeContainer;

        return "direct:myRoute." + n;
    }


    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        if (route != null) {
            route.configure();
        }
    }

    public abstract static class Route {        
        abstract public void configure();
    }

}
```

Requests that are sent to `direct:mainRoute` work.
During Camel startup I see in the console:

```
Building main route!
Context: SpringCamelContext(camel-1) with spring id org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext:/sample-route
Building nested route!
Context: SpringCamelContext(camel-1) with spring id org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext:/sample-route
```

and when I send a request to `direct:mainRoute`, the output is:

```
{"status":"SUCCESS"}
```

HOWEVER, if I comment out (1) above, and uncomment (2), Camel starts up with the same output to the console, but when I send a request to `direct:mainRoute`, the execution of the route fails with the exception:

```
org.apache.camel.component.direct.DirectConsumerNotAvailableException: No consumers available on endpoint: Endpoint[direct://myRoute.2].
```

**To Clarify:** my problem is because I would actually like NOT to instantiate `RouteContainer` each time I call its route, as I do in (3). This is why I instantiate them at point (2) and plug the `Route` instance into it...

So I would like `MainRouteBuilder` to look like this:

```
public class MainRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder
{
    public static CamelContext camelContext;

    public static boolean returnLabel = true;

    public static RouteBuilder nestedRouteBuilder;

    RouteContainer routeContainer = new RouteContainer();

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception
    {
        System.out.println("Building main route!");
        System.out.println("Context: " + getContext());

        camelContext = getContext();

        from("direct:mainRoute")
        .to(routeContainer.getMyRoute(2))
        //I may want to call it again like this:
        //.to(routeContainer.getMyRoute(3))
        ;

        returnLabel = false;

        //configure direct:myRoute.2

        includeRoutes(nestedRouteBuilder);      
    }

}
```

My assumption is that maybe the nested route `direct:myRoute.2` is created in the wrong `CamelContext`, but the console output tells me it is not so.

Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you explain a bit what the idea behind the having dynamic route creation done this way? Makes it easier to understand the code.

Comment: @Souciance Eqdam Rashti: I don't want to hard code route names/labels all over the application.

Comment: Well I have created routes dynamically by using property injection via property files. So my routes endpoint url change depending on whether it is the test, qa or production environment even though it is the same route. If you think that might be a good approach let me know I can write some code in an answer.

Comment: @Souciance Eqdam Rashti: if I get you right, it is not relevant to the described problem. In my case, I create routes, and I would like to call them as ordinary methods, not by a String attached to them. It works partially, as I explained above. But not completely. Since when you switch from (1) to (2) above, something strange happens. Which I don't quite understand. My mission is to understand why step (2) does not work and fix the issue, while retaining the general design of referring to routes as ordinary methods.

Comment: I had to go into the trouble of creating new instances as I do in (2) and plugging into them the anonymous class, since I do not want to do the instantiation within the route definition itself; as I explained in point (3) above.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Route configuration != route execution

It seems that you are confusing route configuration with route execution. We've all been there ;-)

When you configure the RouteBuilder in `MainRouteBuilder#configure()`, the method is only is only executed **once** when your Camel app bootstraps, in order to set up the routing logic. The DSL creates the plumbing for the route (Processors, Interceptors, etc.) and **that's** what the route runtime will be.

**Point to bring home:** The DSL is **not** executed over and over again with every Exchange.

In other words, Camel does not do what you point out in (3). It doesn't execute `new RouteContainer().getMyRoute(2)` for every single Exchange. Think about it: the bytecode for `configure()` is only executed when configuring Camel, and the bytecode instantiates an object of class `RouteContainer` and it invokes the `getMyRoute` with argument `2`. The resulting object is fed into the [`SendProcessor`](https://camel.apache.org/maven/camel-2.15.0/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/processor/SendProcessor.html) that the `to()` DSL generates.

### Analysis of your code

Now, with regards to why your code doesn't yield the result you expect.

You have a problem with the state-keeping of `RouteContainer`. Every time you call `getMyRoute` you overwrite the instance variable `route`. So it's impossible for your current code to call `getMyRoute` several times (with different `n`s) and then call `includeRoutes` just once at the end, because only the most recently generated route will be added.

I also don't like masking the Camel `Route` class with a class of your own, just to act as a placeholder, but that brings up a different discussion you didn't ask for.

### Simpler solution

Instead of your `RouteContainer` class, here's a `RouteGenerator` class that creates routes and returns the `direct:` endpoint to the caller. It keeps track of all the routes in an internal `Set`.

```
public class RouteGenerator {

    private Set<RouteBuilder> routeBuilders = new HashSet<>();

    public String generateRoute(final int n) {

        routeBuilders.add(new RouteBuilder() {
            @Override public void configure() throws Exception {
                System.out.println("Building nested route!");
                System.out.println("Context: " + getContext());

                from("direct:myRoute." + n)
                    .transform() .simple("number: " + n)
                    .to("stream:out")
                    .process(new Processor() {
                        @Override
                        public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                            Response response = new Response();
                            response.setStatus(Status.SUCCESS);
                            exchange.getOut().setBody(response);
                        }
                    });
            }
        });

        return "direct:myRoute." + n;

    }

    public Set<RouteBuilder> getRouteBuilders() {
        return routeBuilders;
    }

}
```

And here is your `MainRouteBuilder`, which instantiates the `RouteGenerator` only once, and can generate as many routes as you wish.

Once you finish configuring your routes, you just iterate over the accumulated `RouteBuilders` and include them:

```
public class MainRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {

    public static CamelContext camelContext;

    public static RouteGenerator routeGenerator = new RouteGenerator();

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Building main route!");
        System.out.println("Context: " + getContext());

        camelContext = getContext();

        from("direct:mainRoute")
            .to(routeGenerator.generateRoute(2));


        for (RouteBuilder routeBuilder : routeGenerator.getRouteBuilders()) {
            includeRoutes(routeBuilder);
        }
    }

}
```

### EDIT: Why doesn't your option (2) work?

After debugging for some time, I realised why you're seeing this effect.

Extracted from [the Java Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html):

> As with instance methods and variables, an inner class is associated
>   with an instance of its enclosing class and has direct access to that
>   object's methods and fields.

In (2), you create an instance of `Route` within the scope of the initial `RouteContainer` object, acting as the outer object. The `Route` object retains the outer `RouteContainer` as its outer object. The `from()` and subsequent methods are therefore being invoked on that **initial `RouteContainer` (`RouteBuilder`) object, not on the new `RouteContainer` you create later**, which is the one you provide to the upper RouteBuilder (which is associated to the CamelContext).

That's why your `direct:myRoute.2` is not being added to the Camel Context, because it's being created in a different route builder.

Also note that the console output of (2):

```
Building main route!
Context: CamelContext(camel-1)
Building nested route!
Context: CamelContext(camel-2)
Added!
```

The second route is being added to a different context `camel-2`. This new context is created by Camel lazily when it adds the route to the old RouteBuilder, which hasn't been associated to any Camel Context yet.

Note that the the Camel Context of the initial RouteContainer (created in the instance variable initialization) is `null`, because you assign the `MainRouteBuilder.camelContext` property later on.

You can see how two different route builders are being used by adding the following `println` statements:

**Inside Route#configure:**

```
System.out.println("RouteContainer to which route is added: " + RouteContainer.this.hashCode());
```

**Inside MainRouteBuilder#configure, just before `includeRoutes`:**

```
System.out.println("RouteContainer loaded into Camel: " + nestedRouteBuilder.hashCode());
```

With (1), the hashcode **is the same**. With (2), the hashcode **is different**, clearly showing that there are two different RouteBuilders in play (one which contains the route, and the one that's loaded into the Context, which does not include the route).

---

Source: I'm a Apache Camel PMC member and committer.

Comment: Thanks. Haven't tested it yet. Here are the most important points that were left unanswered: Eventually you create RouteBuilder instances, with configure methods that contain specific code, and you call those configure methods (through includeRoutes). How is it crucially different from what I am doing? Eventually I create RouteBuilder instances with configure methods that contain specific code, and invoke them, also through includeRoutes. Could you explain why code (1) works and (2) doesn't? If the console shows that `direct:myRoute.2` is created, then why is the exception?

Comment: You're right. Let me get to the bottom on this! Debugging.

Comment: @rapt done! Also, notice that the output from (2) is: Building main route!
Context: CamelContext(camel-1)
Building nested route!
Context: CamelContext(camel-2)
Added!
----------- Notice that the second route is being added to a different, lazily created new Camel Context (camel-2).

Comment: saw your earlier reply this morning on the different contexts and realized it could not be something with the different CamelContexts since I forced the same context by the RouteContainer constructor (see above). Then I looked at code (1) and your code and saw the similarities... the `from(..).to(..)` etc happens in the context (nothing to do with CamelContext) of the original RB instance which was added to the right CamelContext (if you force that fact). While in (2), `from(..).to(..)` manipulates the internals of right RB, but it's a newly created RB which is added to the context.

Comment: Yes, but have a look at my edited reply above. I've made it clearer. What's happening is that, in (2), the RB you pass to includeRoutes() is **not** the RB which is in the context/namespace of the Route instance. When the anonymous class is created, it associates the outer class forever to that anonymous class. So when Camel invokes the `configure()` method, it ends up adding the route to the **OLDER** RB which is not the one that you're passing to `includeRoutes()` any longer. What you're experiencing is a misunderstanding of scopes and namespaces of anonymous classes in Java, in my opinion.

Comment: Take into account that the invocation to from() from within Route is a call to the RouteBuilder#from() method of the **outer** object at that point. In (1) you are setting **that** object in `MainRouteBuilder.nestedRouteBuilder` which is then used in `includeRoutes()`, that's why it works. In (2), you are setting a new RouteContainer object which is not the same onto which `Route` will be adding its route when `configure()` gets invoked.

Comment: I recall I realized that fact about the need to call the java-dsl code (from(), to() etc) within the context of the original RB instance sometime ago when I made the decision to initialize a RB instance for each method call like I did in (1), but have been busy for sometime with something totally else and forgot the details. Since your way does not make the separation between the anonymous class and the encapsulating RB instance, I will do it this way. Good catch, I will change my code and test and if it works will choose your answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103014/discussion-between-raulk-and-rapt).

Comment: Hi, any feedback? I don't think it's fair to hold off marking the answer as correct on the basis of testing my solution. You didn't ask for an alternative in your question, just the reasoning why your current code doesn't work. I provided that and you acknowledged it already. The alternative solution was just an extra bonus from my side, in which I invested time and effort, so it feels unfair to delay the award unnecessarily.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I got caught up in another task yesterday. Just tested it this morning and works perfectly. So thanks for the insights and the clear explanation. You deserve the reward :) As a side note - we've discussed this point previously: when I spawn `new RouteBuilder()`s they are created each in a new `CamelContext` so somehow need to force the original main context into the child RB - I did it by making my `Route` extend RB, then saving the main context as a static, and pushing it into the child RB through a constructor, as I've shown in my code above. All's well that ends well.